Which note to use with trill

Ciaccona from Partita 2 in D minor from 6 Sonatas and Partitas for violin solo by JS Bach
The second to last note on the last line has a trill. I just wanted to check which note to use with C. Sounds a bit funny to me. Thanks

D flat would be a lot funnier!

Use D. In Baroque music trills begin on the diatonic note above the written note unless otherwise specified.
